# How can I include the participantID when calling the CiviEvent registration form?

Tags: civievent, forms, registration, participants

Is there a way to pre-fill the event registration form with participant data?

Why should I do this?
I tried to send people a link to a pre-filled event registration form. I added all of them to the event as "invited" and asked them to fill out the form (with questions regarding the workshops they like to participate, their diet and so on). I could pre-fill it with data from the contact (using `{contact.checksum}&cid={contact.contact_id}`). But that does not work with the participant. I tried to call the form with `pid={$participantID}`, but the form seems to ignore the data and creates a new participant.

Is there a way to call the form and pre-fill it with participants data?

Comment: Have you tried Webform CiviCRM?

Comment: why does cid and checksum not result in existing data loading? it should. can you paste the path you are sending out (since folk sometimes get them wrong). b/ can you confirm what data is not preloading? I wonder if there is an issue that folk should not register for an event they are already registered for (since you already added them)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @PremPatel I like to call the event registration form for a person that i already registered (i.e. as "invited"). And I like to pre-fill the form with participant data (not only contact data).